# What does stw in assembly actually do, and how does it calculate the memory adress?

Tags: assembly

[Assembler d core sim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPap9.png)

In line 7, if r0=120, after command stw r1, r0, 1 the memory access schould be  MEM[121]=2, but why is it MEM[122] = 2 (was: 0)?

And how can we save something in a value which is saved in the register?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know from this if memory stores bytes at each address or something else, but let's assume each memory location stores a byte, which is called byte addressing.

It looks like it is doing scaling.  Scaling is multiplying an index to obtain a byte offset, and this is necessary when data type occupies more than one address, such as a 16-bit value taking two bytes in memory — and thus also taking two memory addresses.

Here, the indexes are 0,1,2,3 and the scaling factor is 2, because two addresses are used for every word stored — thus, after scaling, there are offsets of 0,2,4,6, corresponding to the indexes.

These offsets are then added to the base address, 120, yielding addresses 120,122,124,126, where 2 bytes are stored at each address to compose a 16-bit word.

What they're not showing is that on line 5, MEM[121] must also have been written, and they're not really clear about endian either, but it looks like MEM[120] = 1 % 256, and MEM[121] = 1 / 256, i.e. if memory is bytes, then that's how two bytes would store the simple value 1, in little endian form.

On the other hand they could mean that MEM[addr]=value is a double-byte write without telling us what the endian is.

However, a machine that uses byte addressing would usually also have a `stb` store byte instruction, otherwise there's little point to being byte addressable.  It would be interesting to see how they describe the MEM[addr]=value, with `stb` since technically it would need to indicate only a byte write instead of double-byte write.

Comment: I was told that the d-core simulator doesn't only work with the 16 registers, but also has a RAM. So when we use stw or ldw in d-core sim we are working with the RAM. And yes, you are right, the addresses can each store 2 bytes so the adresses are 120,122...

Comment: Yes, the physical storage of the computer consists of both registers and memory.  An another note, we develop algorithms, which consist of logical variables and execution steps — these both are mapped to the physical resources of the computer: logical variables to some registers or physical memory, and algorithm steps to machine code instructions telling the processor how to do the algorithm.

Comment: I feel I should point out that this is not usually how memory offsets work on actual hardware. Generally speaking, you have to do the "scaling" yourself, e.g. write `stw r1, r0, 2` to store at `MEM[122]` assuming that `r0 = 120`. This is typically how you would do it in ARM, MIPS, or RISC-V.

Comment: @puppydrum64, do you have any statistics to back up that claim?  There's lots of architectures out there and many have addressing modes that scale the index, so not at all unusual.

Comment: @ErikEidt No, I don't. Perhaps a poor assumption on my part. I've worked with about 5 or 6 different assembly languages and none of them scale, so I figured that was the norm. Perhaps a better statement would have been "not every processor works like this and on some of them you'll have to do the scaling yourself."

Comment: @puppydrum64, ARM has scaled loads & stores, it is a shift happy architecture, so does shifts on many instructions including indexed loads;  x86 & x64, 68020, also have scaled index loads & stores.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I misunderstood. You can definitely do post-increment with `MOVE.W (An)+,Dn` and it will scale the pointer arithmetic, but if you were to specify a constant offset it's not auto-multiplied, e.g. `MOVE.W (1,A2),D0` won't auto-scale the 1 to a 2 and instead causes an alignment fault. That's more or less what I was originally talking about.

Comment: @puppydrum64, yes, I think you're right that a 68000 won't scale a constant offset, though it will add the proper amount for the pre-decrement and post-increment modes.  Otherwise 68000 has no scaling.  However, the 68020 introduced scaling of index registers, so can do `MOVE.W d(An,Xn), Dn` where `Xn` is `An` or `Dn` qualified by a size of `.W` or `.L`, and scale of 1, 2, 4, or 8.  So, scaling a variable in a register as part of indexing; the `d` is an offset (can be 8, 16, or 32 bits wide) and as you indicated, it is not scaled.